# In Metal Gear Solid 2, why is “privacy guaranteed”?

Tags: video-games, metal-gear-solid

> Otacon: Everything’s going okay?
>
> Snake: The stealth camo’s busted. Landing impact.
>
> Otacon: We must have overused it. Sorry, but you’re going to have to deal
> with it.  You’re not in the military anymore.
>
> Snake: Right. I didn’t plan on relying on this gadget anyway.
>
> Otacon: The private sector’s not so bad, is it? Privacy guaranteed…
>
> Snake: I’m happy as long as no one gives me any more unwanted gifts

What does he mean by “*privacy guaranteed*”?

Is it because of the stealth camo? But it was busted, so why?

Comment: No obligation, of course, but I notice that you have a number of questions that have good answers, but aren't accepted (and there are no comments indicating what else you're looking for). Don't forget you can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. (And incidentally, if you view the tour, you'll get another badge)

Answer (score 13):

My read on the line is that Otacon is simply stating that, by working in the private sector, the military no longer has the ability to inspect and control Solid Snake's personal life. One of the consequences of military service is that Command generally gets to control most aspects of your life, down to where you sleep, what you eat, and what you can say in public.

As regards the quip about the stealth camo, one of the benefits of working for the military is that they provide the equipment. Without that sort of backing, they either can't afford to replace the stealth camo, or can't readily source it (since it's likely proprietary military technology). In this case, a later line in the scene hints that Mei Ling got them the camo.

> Snake      : Diverting toys from the SSCEN (U.S. Army Soldier Systers Center)
> again? Give her a message from me: someone will find out sooner
> or later. She's better off assuming it's sooner and quit while
> she's safe.

And in case you're curious about the "unwanted gifts" line, the next line is:

> Otacon     : You mean that thing with Naomi?

This is likely in reference to [Naomi Hunter](https://metalgear.fandom.com/wiki/Naomi_Hunter#Shadow_Moses_Incident) and her role in injecting Snake with nanobots, including [FOXDIE](https://metalgear.fandom.com/wiki/FOXDIE).

Comment: Aye. Private sector = private life.

Comment: We must have overuse it.Sorry but you’re going to have to deal with it .You’re not on the military anymore.       Is this means the military could fix the stealth camo?

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley One of the benefits of working for the military is that they provide the equipment. Without that sort of backing, they either can't afford to replace the stealth camo, or can't readily source it (since it's likely proprietary military technology).